# Browser generates empty paragraph that has no source in html source

Tags: html

My website contains a table

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Alpha Beta Gamma Delta</div>
            <table class="panel-body table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Some Text</td>
                        <td><p><a href="https://example.com">A Link</a></p>
                        <p><a href="https://example.com">Another Link</a></td></p>
                    </tr>                           
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, there is an empty line above the table content:
[image]
The source code does not contain this, but looking at the source as firefox and chrome display it in the developer tools, there clearly is an empty `<p></p>` inserted before the table body.

This paragraph appears seemingly for no reason, out of thin air. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The devil lies in the detail:
[image: comparison]

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Alpha Beta Gamma Delta</div>
                <table class="panel-body table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Some Text</td>
                            <td><p><a href="https://example.com">A Link</a></p>
                            <p><a href="https://example.com">Another Link</a></td></p>
                        </tr>                           
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Alpha Beta Gamma Delta</div>
                <table class="panel-body table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Some Text</td>
                            <td><p><a href="https://example.com">A Link</a></p>
                            <p><a href="https://example.com">Another Link</a></p></td>
                        </tr>                           
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The difference is that the first version is not actually valid html: It starts with `<td><p>` and ends with `</td></p>` instead of `</p></td>`.
It's curious that both browsers reacted in the same way to this.

It seems like anything wrongly added to the table is added before it, as a stray `-->` without starting counterpart shows as well.